# Why is a Photoshop CC Action skipping over an inactive step?

Tags: actions

**PREMISE:**
I have 2 actions. One has a inactive step, the goal being is I want it to stop before this particular step so that I can manually handle do work. I also have another action which has all steps active.

**ATTEMPT:** I wanted to combine the steps of both of those actions into 1 action thus saving the need to use 2 actions.

**PROBLEM** When I had the last step in 'Crop Adjust 1' set to inactive, it would run and stop before the last step, allowing me to manually edit. When I tried to combine the steps of 'Crop Adjust 1' with '..Gallery Frame..1' as show in 'Crop Adjust 2,' the inactive step would just be skipped over.

**GOAL:** Have the Action stop at the inactive step, let me manually do work, then let me resume the rest of the steps in the action. Is this possible?

[image: Actions With Inactive Step Vs. Combined Action With Inactive Step]

Comment: Thats kindof the purpose of inactive, to skip the step. Use a stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must insert a Stop.

Check ** allow continue**.

When you play the action it will stop showing the **Stop message**.

Click the **Stop** button.

Now you can go back to your work.

Hitting the **play** button your action will continue where it stopped.

Image below:

[image]